# JS Fiddle code does not work after downloading whole code to the Local computer

Tags: javascript, html, local, jsfiddle

I found example fiddle web page:

jsfiddle.net/yijiang/6FLsM/2

Now I followed examples from others and tried to download (right click and Save As) using latest Chrome from these links:

`jsfiddle.net/yijiang/6FLsM/2/show`

`jsfiddle.net/yijiang/6FLsM/2/show/light`

But none of these worked on a local computer..
What am I doing wrong? 
How can I make it fully working on a local computer (not partially working)?

Comment: That's because downloading the page doesn't include all of the additional scripts that jsfiddle loads during execution. Other things may fail as well due to cross-origin issues and depending on whether or not you're connected to the Internet.

Comment: You cannot run functions by simply plotting them on a new line like in Fiddle. You have to use window.onload.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the html code inside the iframe of the bottom right div which should work when saved to a file with .html and opened in a browser

Comment: That worked! I needed to do in Chrome: Right click -> 'View frame source' on a bottom right Div and than once that opens in a new tab - save that page as a new Html.. Than it worked on my local computer..